# Как удалить лишнюю строку в цикле

Tags: c#

```
private static StringBuilder Zapis = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
private static ManagementObjectSearcher GetMonitor = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_DesktopMonitor");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in GetMonitor.Get())
{
   Zapis.AppendFormat("Разрешение экрана:" + string.Format(queryObj["ScreenWidth"] + "x" + queryObj["ScreenHeight"]));
}
```

После записи в файл появляется вот такая вот строка:

- Разрешение экрана: x

  ```
   Разрешение экрана: 1920x1080
  ```

Появляется лишняя строчка 1-ая - `Разрешение экрана: x` Как убрать эту строчку?               }

Comment: у вас 1 монитор в свойствах системы показывается? зы: зачем вам `format`-функции, если вы их не используете по назначению. зы2: проверьте наличие значения, прежде чем добавлять да и отфильтруется. `if(queryObj["ScreenWidth"])`{ zapis.append(...); }

Comment: @teran, `format` использовал на худой случай) пробовал без него тоже самое :( Но постоянно вылазит 1-ая строчка с пустым `x`

Comment: поэтому я и спросил, нет ли у вас в диспетчере устройств второго монитора. Вам запрос возвращает 2 записи, одна какая то таинственная, вторая - к текущему монитору.

Comment: В диспетчере устройств нету 2 монитора! Всего одна запись: `Универсальный монитор PnP`
`

Comment: можете для интереса вывести и другие поля, и посмотреть что в них, и что за первый монитор рисует. Возможно можно отфильтровать по `StatusInfo`. А виртуальных рабочих столов нет?

Comment: Виртуальных столов нету!.Очень странно просто если я использую такой метод в консоли, то всё нормально отображается! А вот почему после записи в файл появляется лишняя строка не понятно.

Comment: На сайте не принято вписывать ответ в вопрос, вы уже поставили галку -- это достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас пустые queryObj["ScreenWidth"] и queryObj["ScreenHeight"], напишите что-то типа:

```
    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in GetMonitor.Get())
    {
        if(queryObj["ScreenWidth"] == null || queryObj["ScreenHeight"] == null)
            continue;

        Zapis.AppendFormat("Разрешение экрана:" + string.Format(queryObj["ScreenWidth"] + "x" + queryObj["ScreenHeight"]));
//      var str = $"Разрешение экрана: {queryObj["ScreenWidth"]} x {queryObj["ScreenHeight"]}";
//      str.Dump();
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот способ помог решить данную проблему!

Comment: ответ, к сожалению, из области костылей, или лечения симптомов, а не болячки. Корректным решением было бы либо определить, что за объект возвращается с пустыми значениями, либо как отобрать только единственный нужный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте точку остановки и пройдите по программе. Думаю значения ScreenWidth и ScreenHeight могут быть пустыми. Может есть какой-то виртуальный монитор.

И я бы использовал такую запись:

```
Zapis.AppendFormat("Разрешение экрана: {0} х {1}", var1, var2);
```

Comment: это скорее монитор, который подключался к системе когда-то раньше.